# DNS Resolution Oddity

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, services

In Windows 10, I frequently have to manually restart the "DNS Client" service in order to successfully ping a host, even if I can ping the host by IP address, and where nslookup seems to correctly resolve the DNS name to its equivalent IP address.

I'm trying to figure out what causes the behaviour depicted below:

`PS C:\Users\Joe> ping server01.domain.pri
Ping request could not find host server01.domain.pri. Please check the name and try again.
PS C:\Users\Joe> nslookup server01.domain.pri
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.9
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    server01.domain.pri
Address:  192.168.70.10
PS C:\Users\Joe> ping 192.168.70.10
Pinging 192.168.70.10 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.70.10: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=126
Reply from 192.168.70.10: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=126
Ping statistics for 192.168.70.10:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 27ms, Maximum = 28ms, Average = 27ms
Control-C
PS C:\Users\Joe>`

Any insight is helpful, thank you.

Comment: what is the output of `ping -a 192.168.70.10`? Why do you get gtserver01 when pinging server01? Check your DNS records for both names, check your reverse DNS records. Does it also happen after a `ipconfig /flushdns`? Does the ping by name work after the successful nslookup? Check your `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file!

Comment: Edited the question to show server01 rather than gtserver01 (my failed attempt at obfuscation, as I missed deleting that one instance of "gt" before posting!).
Problem persists after /flushdns, as well as after the successful nslookup resolution.  Only thing that solves is restart of Windows "DNS Client" service.
etc/hosts file is clean, unedited.

Comment: Really strange. What about the `ping -a'? Any events in windows logs which could point to something strange with the DNS Client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable DNS client permanently

DNS client is not required for DNS resolution it's just a DNS Cache service

I had similar issue

Since i disabled DNS service haven't had these issues

Comment: I am not sure why the cache would have been incorrect, but as you point out, disabling the DNS Client service does seem to resolve this issue.  Thank you.